# How to animate Mechanical gears clogs to be in sync with their teeth rotation

Tags: animation

I saw a video of unusual mechanisms, and I'm trying to replicate a section of the animation.
In the animation video from 00:15sec it has 2 mechanical gears with the teeth perfectly inter combined when they rotate. By my animating gears(teeth) collide when they rotate. I'd like some information, which method to get it correctly animated.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s91uk2CEkZE

[image]

My ones start off good, but as it rotates its obvious the teeth collide.

[image]
[image]

I have included the Blender file with the animation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. delete all animations except the animation of the circle.
2. delete the copy rotation constraint
3. on frame 1 move the gears like this

[image]

then i -> rotation (add rotation keyframe)

4. then move to frame 2 and adapt the rotation of that right gear manually
5. add rotation keyframe again
6. in timeline  a (select all) -> shift-E -> linear extrapolation
7. change to graph editor

[image]

and now carefully check the next frames if it still fits, if not just move that one keyframe on frame 1 up or down so that it fits

[image]

[image]

--- update

wrong:

[image]

right:

[image]

here you see the effect difference between starting at 0 or negative:

[image]

Comment: Hi there Chris, thanks for the help. I've misunderstood one of your steps, the animation is almost correct, but somewhere I have made a mistake. I followed your instructions, can you please check out the file and tell me what I have done wrong.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=R2SAAJ8Z" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/R2SAAJ8Z/)

Comment: gear1 should start for z-rotation negative to positive, if the z-rotation starts at 0, it doesn't rotate relative to gear2.

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Appreciate you help, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome